# Clarification of syntax used

Tags: powershell, syntax, where-clause

Can someone explain me this syntax? I think it didn't work, so if you can help me to find another syntax.

```
$fichesAEnvoyer = @($fiches | where {($_.TypeFiche -eq '2') -and (($_.Causes -eq '') -or ($_.Causes -eq $null) -or ($_.Causes.Count -eq 0) -or ($_.ActionCorrective -eq '') -or ($_.ActionCorrective -eq $null) -or ($_.DateActionCorrective -eq '') -or ($_.DateActionCorrective -eq $null) -or ($_.ActionPreventive -eq '') -or ($_.ActionPreventive -eq $null) -or ($_.DateActionPreventive -eq '') -or ($_.DateActionPreventive -eq $null) )})
```

I don't understand why there is `$_` instead of `$fiches`

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347728.aspx

Comment: `$_` represents the current object in the pipeline. If that is not your issue then we need more than _I think it didn't work_. Did it work or not. What did you expect to happen. What is `$fiches`. You have quite the complicated conditions there. Break them up individually to see what is happening. We can't help without sample data.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$_** is a variable that the **where** cmdlet creates to represent the current object in the pipeline. For example, if you do:

```
1,2,3 | where {$_ -ge 2} | Write-Host
```

Then **$_** will be set to 1 followed by 2, followed by 3.